# How to reverse an array of characters that make up a sentence

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to take a array of Characters that spell out a sentence backwards (or out of order) with the words separated by spaces to distinguish them and re-order them in the correct/reversed format so instead of the character array spelling out *World Good Hello* it would spell out *Hello Good World* like this ['H','e','l','l','o',' ','G','o','o','d',' ','W','o','r','l','d']

This is more or less a shot in the dark.

**In the end I would like to return it back as an array of characters.**

**Code:**

```
  class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // World Good Hello
    // reverse to: Hello Good World

    char[] chrArray = new char[] {'W','o','r','l','d',' ','G','o','o','d',' ','H','e','l','l','o'};

    String str = String.valueOf(chrArray);
    String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
    char[] result = new char[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {

      for (int h = 0; h < strArray[i].length(); h++) {

        char[] temp = new char[strArray[i].charAt(h)];
        temp[temp.length - 1] = ' ';
        char[] both = Arrays.copyOf(result, result.length);

        List<character> temp2 = System.arraycopy(temp, 0, both, result.length, temp.length);
        result = temp2.toCharArray();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You are missing imports. And you mean `Character`, not `character`. And `List` has no `toCharArray()` method

Comment: And by the way: there is no need to use lists.

Comment: `System.arraycopy` returns void

Comment: You are missing imports. Use Eclipse or any other IDE to help you organize imports more efficiently and automatically

Comment: @fatcook & Andy Turner - Imports are usually not posted with a question as it is easy to get your IDE to import it for you when you test the code. Hunter - `result.length` is **0** when the loop execute for the first round.

Comment: @TungstenX they are not usually posted with the question, but the [originally included error message](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54704329/revisions) makes it clear that is the problem.

Comment: @Hunter Please get the question heading correct, stackoverflow community is not interview practice site, so please do not post these titles.

Comment: "If anyone has a better solution" of course somebody might; but what is the value of that to you? Interviews are about seeing how a candidate thinks around a problem, not simply writing code, but thinking critically about it and identifying strengths and weaknesses of the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String reverseWords(String sentence) {
    String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(sentence.length());

    for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (buf.length() > 0)
            buf.append(' ');
        buf.append(words[i]);
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Use `reverseWords(...).toCharArray()` to get *char array*.

Comment: would you be able to return it back as an array of characters

Comment: `reverseWords("World Good Hello").toCharArray()`

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code would be enough to reverse:

```
String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
for(int i =strArray.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    System.out.print(strArray[i] + " ");
}
```

this will output : `Hello Good World`

Comment: Do you know how to to return it back as an array of characters as well or basically initialize the variable called (result)?